# How to populate a JTable using List<Object>

Tags: java

So I need to populate a `JTable` using data from

```
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

I'm using NetBeans. I have tried many different things that haven't seemed to work for me.

This is my code:

```
public void login()
{

    Query queryPK = CryptoCurrencyPUEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t.email, t.user_id FROM usertbl t");
    Query queryFK = CryptoCurrencyPUEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t.curreny, t.amount FROM CURRENCY t WHERE user_fk=?1 ");

    List<Object[]> results = queryPK.getResultList();
    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
    {
        if(results.get(i)[0].equals(loginEmail))
        {
            int fk = (int)(results.get(i)[1]);
            System.out.println(fk);
            queryFK.setParameter(1, fk);
            List<Object[]> currencyTBLresluts = queryFK.getResultList();

            Currency cur = new Currency();


            String[] currTBLheadings = {"Currency","Amount"};

            // This is where I would put the data into the table
            // Not sure how I am meant to do that
            // jTableCurr.setModel(); maybe?

        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an one of many example that you could use it:

```
    //declaring columns
    String col[] ={"Currency", "Amount"};
    //TableModel
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel (col,0);
    //Your awesome table with tableModel *injected*
    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

public void login() {

    Query queryPK = CryptoCurrencyPUEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t.email, t.user_id FROM usertbl t");
    Query queryFK = CryptoCurrencyPUEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t.curreny, t.amount FROM CURRENCY t WHERE user_fk=?1 ");

    List<Object[]> results = queryPK.getResultList();
    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        if(results.get(i)[0].equals(loginEmail)) {
            int fk = (int)(results.get(i)[1]);
            System.out.println(fk);
            queryFK.setParameter(1, fk);
            List<Object[]> currencyTBLresluts = queryFK.getResultList();
            if(currencyTBLresluts != null && !currencyTBLresluts.isEmpty()){
                Object[] array = currencyTBLresluts.toArray(new Object[currencyTBLresluts.size()]);
                ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).addRow(array);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have come right. Thank you so much for you time.

Comment: If this answer satisfy you mark as answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I came right after looking though the api

```
public void whenUserLogsIn(){

    Query queryPK   = CryptoCurrencyPUEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t.email, t.user_id FROM usertbl t");
    Query queryFK   = CryptoCurrencyPUEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t.curreny, t.amount FROM CURRENCY t WHERE user_fk=?");

    List<Object[]> results = queryPK.getResultList();


    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
    {
        Object[] userArr = results.get(i);
        if(userArr[0].equals(loginEmail))
        {

            int userID = (int)(userArr[1]);
            System.out.println(userID);
            queryFK.setParameter(1, userID);

            List<Object[]> currencyTBLresluts = queryFK.getResultList();

            System.out.println("No of currency "+ currencyTBLresluts.size());


            String[] currTBLheadings = {"Currency","Amount"};

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(currTBLheadings, currencyTBLresluts.size());
            for (Object[] currencyTBLreslut : currencyTBLresluts) 
            {
                model.addRow(currencyTBLreslut); 
                System.out.println(currencyTBLreslut[0]);
            }

            jTableCurr.setModel(model);  
        }
    }    
}
```